# AWS- Angular real time notification using lambda websocket API

Tags: node.js, angular, amazon-web-services

My water level hardware device sending the data to our node js API which i am saving in the mongo db and i want to show it on the angular app in real time.
What service of aws i can use to get the real time notification on the angular app.

**I want in this senario**

hardware hit to my node api. It will save the data to mongodb. After that API should broadcast some event which will be subscribe by angular application

I have seen SNS,SQS,amplify but nothing work for me

Comment: I don't think you necessarily need a new AWS service to do this for you. You just need to add a WebSocket connection between your Angular app and your backend server.

Comment: how will I create a web socket connection? you mean custom

Comment: You have a custom written back-end nodeJS web server, correct? And you have a custom written front-end Angular app, correct? So I'm suggesting adding custom code to both of those to establish a WebSocket connection between the front-end and back-end so that the back-end can push notifications to the front-end in real time.

Answer (score 0):

I got the solution for this

1. I have created a WebSocket lambda API.
2. make a connection from the client(Angular)
3. generated connection id stored in the dynamodb
4. Create an SQS service and make the WebSocket trigger with this SQS.
   5  when my hardware hits the API I will send a message to SQS which will trigger
   Websocket lambda function and I will receive a message in the client(Angular)